# Java 8 Update 25: Security settings won't allow a website even after adding to the list

Tags: windows-8, security, java, java-applet

I've been attempting to allow a website to run an unsigned applet, and even after multiple re-installs and security changes, Java still informs me upon launching the applet that security settings aren't sufficient. I've added the website to the exception list, set it to high, (as low as the security goes), and I'm not sure what to do now. Thanks!

Comment: The exception list should be URLs which begin with http:// or https:// so like `http://sitetorunjavafrom.com`

Comment: I have the same problem, and I suppose it can only be a bug!